# Unity not resolve nested generic arguments using the configuration file, but resolve using UnityContainer

Tags: c#, generics, unity-container, app-config

I'm trying to load the Unity configuration from file Unity.config. In the implementation of the interfaces used generic-arguments
**My configuration file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">

  <assembly name="TestUnityGeneric" />
  <namespace name="TestUnityGeneric"/>

  <container name="Entity">

    <register type="IEventBus`2[IEvent`1[long],long]" mapTo="TestEventBus`2[IEvent`1[long],long]"></register>

    <register type="ISender" mapTo="TestSender">
      <constructor>
        <param name="eventBus" dependencyType="IEventBus`2[IEvent`1[long], long]" />
      </constructor>
    </register>
  </container>
</unity>
```

this is configuration not working. **BUT next C# code worked:**

```
public interface IEvent<out Key>
{
    Key SourceId { get; }
}

public interface IEventBus<E, in Key>
    where E : IEvent<Key>
{
    void Publish(E @event);
}

public class TestEventBus<E, Key> : IEventBus<E, Key>
where E : IEvent<Key>
{
    public void Publish(E @event)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message published!");
    }
}

public interface ISender
{
    void SendToBus(string message);
}

public class TestSender : ISender
{
    private IEventBus<IEvent<long>, long> _bus { get; set; }

    public TestSender(IEventBus<IEvent<long>,long> eventBus)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sender Initialized");
        _bus = eventBus;
    }

    public void SendToBus(string message)
    {
        IEvent<long> env = new TestEvent
        {
            SourceId = 1,
            Message = message
        };

        _bus.Publish(env);
    }
}

public class TestEvent : IEvent<long>
{
    public long SourceId { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // It Is not worked: Exception: "GenericArguments violates the constraint of type paremeter "E""
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer().LoadConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UnityContainer"]);

        // This is worked
        /*
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

        IEventBus<IEvent<long>, long> bus = new TestEventBus<IEvent<long>, long>();

        container.RegisterInstance<IEventBus<IEvent<long>, long>>(bus);

        container.RegisterType<ISender, TestSender>(new TransientLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IEventBus<IEvent<long>, long>)));
        */

        var sender = container.Resolve<ISender>();

        sender.SendToBus("MyMessage");

        Console.ReadKey();   
    }
}
```

ALL PROJECT CODE: [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f6vi0tnyj1yptnb/TestUnityGeneric.rar?dl=0)

Comment: Are you normally able to use primitive names like that in your configuration file? What happens if you use `System.Int64` instead of `long` everywhere?

Comment: It doesn't help that in your code, `ExampleGeneric` isn't actually generic... please post a complete sample that *genuinely* demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet  Using System.Int64 not solve the problem

Comment: @JonSkeet I create test project[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/f6vi0tnyj1yptnb/TestUnityGeneric.rar?dl=0)

Comment: While having a complete test project elsewhere is good, it's also good to have a minimal example *in the question* without having to download anything. You've now provided more code than is needed to demonstrate the problem (I strongly suspect) but without matching the introductory part of the question. I will see if I can find time to have a look at all of this later, but you could definitely still improve the question.

Comment: As it turned out , Unity does not understand the nested generic in Unity.config file. SOLUTION: using Alias, and Alias ​​One should not use other alias.

Comment: @JonSkeet thank, temporary solution found (see question)

Comment: If you have solved the problem by yourself please write an answer and accept it, instead of including the solution in the question itself.

Comment: @Konamiman Thank you, I'll do it

Comment: @AlexandrMedvedev Great, thanks! This is the standard behavior in StackOverflow when you find the solution to your problem by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## RESOLVED

As it turned out , Unity does not understand the nested generic in Unity.config file. SOLUTION: using Alias, and Alias ​​One should not use other alias. This configuratiion - worked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">

  <assembly name="TestUnityGeneric" />
  <namespace name="TestUnityGeneric"/>

  <alias alias="IEventLong" type="TestUnityGeneric.IEvent`1[System.Int64], TestUnityGeneric" />

  <container name="Entity">
    <register type="IEventBus`2[IEventLong,long]" mapTo="TestEventBus`2[IEventLong,long]"></register>

    <register type="ISender" mapTo="TestSender">
      <constructor>
        <param name="eventBus" dependencyType="IEventBus`2[IEventLong, long]" />
      </constructor>
    </register>
  </container>
</unity>
```